# Changing the default Unix shell without impact on remote logins

Tags: shell, unix, solaris, csh, tcsh

Is it possible to change the default interactive shell of a user on a Unix (Solaris) system without any impact on other software that remotely logs in via the same username (eg: via rsh or ssh).

Rationale: my company sells multi-million dollar machines that still have csh as the default shell. Since csh is very user unfriendly (eg: no history browsing via up/down arrow keys), I proposed to change the default shell to tcsh. Tcsh should be backwards compatible with csh, but apparently it still causes problems for some scripts that remotely login to the machine.

Since there's no real business case to upgrade the shell and to fix all existing scripts, I'm looking for a simple solution with little effort.

Comment: A better solution is to remove csh and tcsh from the system and change the default to a proper shell!

Comment: His _company sells multi-million dollar machines that still have csh as the default shell_. Just "chang[ing] to a proper shell" obviously poses huge operational risks to a company/system/product of that scale. Pretty much all csh users (including myself) know already that csh is evil; trust us, we've read the "top 10 reasons"! The problem is that there isn't enough incentive (by business executives) to justify uprooting and redoing infrastructure whose kinks had been worked out since the 1980s (albeit using csh), especially when

Comment: the company already has relationships with clients, for example in the financial industries, investment banks, who are paying millions and demanding new changes, not infrastructure overhauls so programmers' lives can be better. Does csh pose an operational risk on its own? Yes, because programmers are more prone to mistakes, _e.g._ quoting hell. But those mistakes can be worked out during development and testing, while migrating thousands of deployment, installation, and testing scripts, not to mention all kinds of utilities, already written in csh... It just can't be justified.

Comment: @acheong87 It is definitely a valid question but probably not enough specific to programming to suit SO requirements. Should probably go to serverfault or Unix & Linux.

Comment: @jlliagre - Ah, you're right. I assumed the reason for close was something else.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want distinguish between interactive vs batch shells as opposed to remote vs local ones, right? For the former case, you should examine `$-` variable in your `.profile` script.

Thinking more about this, `csh` is not that great at providing the same information as Bourne shell family. Unless there is indeed a "standard" way for it to detect interactive mode, you have two alternative options:

- Replace `csh` login shell with `ksh` and (after doing the check above) do `exec csh` for interactive sessions.
- In `.login` (or whatever that script is called for `csh`) check the parent process name and if it is `login`, `getty`, `xdm` (or whatever is used for login in your system) then your session is interactive (another alternative is to check the EUID of the parent process).

Comment: Yes I want interactive shells to use csh (or even bash). But at the same time I want all existing scripts to keep using csh. Both interactive and batch shells use the same user account.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't change (again) the default shell. Changing it in the first place from `sh` to `csh` was a mistake. Doing it again would be another one.

There is no point in introducing compatibility breaks, especially with Solaris which is quite serious about maintaining compatibility.

What you might do (although sometimes regarded as controversial) is to create aliases for the affected user accounts, i.e. entries with a different username, password and shell but with an identical uid, gid and home directory.

That would allow remote scripts to still use the legacy environment while the real users would use the shell of their choice.